# Script in Python using subprocess don't work

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on a script where you enter a number and the script creates a folder for you and opens the file explorer in the folder.
But I have problems with it.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os


##saisie du numero de dossier
compostage = str(input('Numero : '))
volume = ('C:')
dossierPrincipal = ('''\\test\\''')
slash = '\\'

##
# Directory 
directory = compostage

# Parent Directory path 
parent_dir = "C:/test/"

#We make only one var for the func
myPath = parent_dir + directory

# Path 
path = os.path.join(myPath) 
##We create a condition to be sure te folder is created
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
    ##We inform the user of the creation of the folder
    print("Directory '% s' well created" % path) 
elif os.path.exists(path):
    ##We inform the user that the folder in question already exists
    print("Directory '% s' already exists" % path) 

##We build the entire path
pathComplet = str(volume+dossierPrincipal+compostage)

##Path verification
print(pathComplet)

##Variable Construction
commandeOuverture = str('('+("""r'explorer """)+'"'+myPath+'"'')')

##Directory verification
print ('La commande est : ', commandeOuverture)

##We open the folder using Popen
subprocess.Popen([commandeOuverture], shell=True)

##We open the folder using Popen if the command above doesn't work
#subprocess.Popen(r'explorer "C:\test\"')
```

The output is:

```
D:\Users\Alex_computer\Documents\Coding\Python\P4_subprocess>main.py
Numero : 5
Directory 'C:/test/5' already exists
C:\test\5
('La commande est : ', '(r\'explorer "C:/test/5")')

D:\Users\Alex_computer\Documents\Coding\Python\P4_subprocess>The specified path was not found.
```

It's what I have when I launch the script

I don't know what to do so it's why I write here in this forum

Comment: Could you provide the full error message from console? It might be helpful to also use the `from pathlib import Path` for handling of paths strings link[https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html]

Comment: Please edit the __full__ error message into your question so we know which line gives that error.

Comment: Have you searched with the error message and discounted all of the possible reasons found in the search results?

Comment: @J.Doe I've edited my question and I've added the "error message" if it can see as an error message...

Comment: @J.Doe Oh, the link you gave me doesn't exist anymore, it returns a 404 not found error

Comment: In addition to pathlib, some more modern string formatting would be good. Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the pathlib Path could make your life really easier.
From the error message you posted, I understand that you try to pass a path with normal `/` ... `('La commande est : ', '(r\'explorer "C:/test/5")')` however windows OS works with the backslash as path delimiter. 
In the code path below you first print a correct windows path in the variable `pathComplet`, however for your command you use myPath that apparently has not a correct path delimiter.

```
##Path verification
print(pathComplet)

##Variable Construction
commandeOuverture = str('('+("""r'explorer """)+'"'+myPath+'"'')')
```

Could u try

```
from pathlib import Path
myPath = Path(myPath)
```

PS: Sorry for messing up the link https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

**Edit:**

Full code that opened the correct directory in the explorer for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

##saisie du numero de dossier
directory = str(input('Numero : '))h
parent_dir = Path("C:/test")
myPath = parent_dir / directory

##We create a condition to be sure te folder is created
if not myPath.exists():
    myPath.mkdir()
    ##We inform the user of the creation of the folder
    print("Directory '% s' well created" % myPath)
elif myPath.exists():
    ##We inform the user that the folder in question already exists
    print("Directory '% s' already exists" % myPath)

##Variable Construction
commandeOuverture = "explorer " + str(myPath)

##We open the folder using Popen
subprocess.Popen(commandeOuverture, shell=True)
```

Comment: Your welcome, could you accept my answer then please?

Comment: If you're going to use pathlib, why use only `pathlib.Path` and stick to the os module for the rest of the operations? Your comment on the post was similarly strange: _It might be helpful to also use the `from pathlib import Path`_ There's more to the library than just that single class.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer with your feedback @AMC. However it shouldn't matter that you feel my comment is **strange**, as long as it solved a problem. Your comments tend to come of rude and create an atmosphere, in which people feel bad about themselves for trying to help others. You are right to critic or try to improve the quality on SO, however you know: _It's not what you say, but how you say it._

Comment: _However it shouldn't matter that you feel my comment is strange, as long as it solved a problem._ I just thought it was worth mentioning, I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually using the command os.makedirs("Your desired path") to test whether the directory you want to create is possible or not.
Generally if you are using a company laptop, creating new folders in C: directory is restricted.
You can try creating a folder in some other drive or Desktop.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The laptop I'm using is mine so I don't have any problems with permissions about creating a folder in the computer, and the command used for creating the path and the folders is working perfectly.... I don't really know what's wrong...